# Forming pandas dataframe from txt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a .txt file consisting of a long string of space-separated numbers

```
12 0 84 9 5 1 49 ......
```

I want to create a pandas dataframe such that the first 500 numbers form the first column, the next 500 numbers the 2nd column, etc. (in total 10000 columns).

How can this be implemented in python?

Comment: If I answer your question, please approve it.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

check out [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).
Example with 10 numbers

```
with open('xx.txt') as f:
    txt = f.read()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

txt_sep = np.array(txt.split())

txt_sep = txt_sep.reshape(5,-1)

df = pd.DataFrame(txt_sep)
```

output:

```
df
   0   1
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```

In your case:

```
txt_sep = txt_sep.reshape(500,-1)
```

But this will only work if you have exactly 10000x500 numbers, but is fixable if this is your case.

Comment: How would this work if I first need to load the text file?